# Django. Remove select_related from queryset

Tags: python, django, orm

Is there any way to remove select related from queryset?

I found, that django add JOIN on count() operation to sql query. 
So, if we have code like this:

```
entities = Entities.objects.select_related('subentity').all()
#We will have INNER JOIN here..
entities.count()
```

I'm looking for a way to remove join. 
One important detail - I got this queryset into django paginator, so I can't simply write

```
Entities.objects.all().count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show the code where you need this, I think refactoring is the best answer here.

If you want quick answer, `entities.query.select_related = False`, but it's rather hacky (and don't forget to restore the value if you will need `select_related` later).

Comment: I don't think that refactoring is needed in our case. Simple situation - insert list of entities into paginator. Just a little bit confused by usage of count and inner join in one query, where it is not needed at all(no filters on related tables). Thanks for answer. That's it.

Comment: As I understand it, by supplying an argument to select_related, you _have_ specified a filter on the related table (if you don't specify any arguments to select_related(), it will grab all related objects, then all objects related to those objects, etc. recursively).

Answer (score 9):

I believe this code comments provide a relatively good answer to the general question that is asked here:

> If select_related(None) is called, the list is cleared.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/db/models/query.py#L735

In the general sense, if you want to do something to the `entities` queryset, but first remove the select_related items from it, `entities.select_related(None)`.

However, that probably doesn't solve your particular situation with the paginator. If you do `entries.count()`, then it *already will* remove the select_related items. If you find yourself with extra JOINs taking place, then it could be several non-ideal factors. It could be that the ORM fails to remove it because of other logic that may or may not affect the count when combined with the select_related.

As a simple example of one of these non-ideal cases, consider `Foo.objects.select_related('bar').count()` versus `Foo.objects.select_related('bar').distinct().count()`. It might be obvious to you that the original queryset does not contain multiple entries, but it is not obvious to the Django ORM. As a result, the SQL that executes contains a JOIN, and there is no universal prescription to work around that. Even applying `.select_related(None)` will not help you.